# How to expand each row in a tableto each distinct value in another table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have a a very basic table with one column with several values in it.  I have another table (we can call it `tableabc` the structure is irrelevant).  For each row in `tableabc` I want it exploded to add a column with each unique `Value` in `TableValue`.  So for example:

```
TableValue
| Value |
| ------ |
| aaa   |
| bbb   |
| ccc  |

tableabc
| c_1 | c_2 |c_3|
|-|-|-|
|1|random|doesnt
|2|data|matter

OutputTable
| c_1 | c_2 |c_3|Value|
|-|-|-|-|
|1|random|doesnt|aaa|
|1|random|doesnt|bbb|
|1|random|doesnt|ccc|
|2|data|matter|aaa|
|2|data|matter|bbb|
|2|data|matter|ccc|
```

What type of action would this be? Obviously not a join, I tried look at "explode" but that seems to be on a column level.  Not sure what this type of relation would be and what that would look like in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as below

```
select *
from tableabc 
cross join TableValue
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]